# Django migration not applied to the DB

Tags: python, mysql, django, migration

I had an Django2.2.3 app, it was working fine. But I had to chane the name of a field in a table, and add another field. Then I ran `./manage.py makemigrations && ./manage.py migrate`. Besides the terminal prompt:

```
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

No error is throwed. But then when I go to the MySQLWorkbench to check the database, it is exactly as I didn't make any change. I tried deleting the migrations and making again, the process ends with no errors but the database don't change. I create another empty database, change the name on settings.py and make migrations and migrate again, and it worked, but when I put the old database name on the settings, it just did not work.

Can someone explain this behavior for me? There is any kind of cache for these information migrations or something? I realy want to know why this is not winrkig as I espect.

Comment: the database has a table/row that indicates which version its up to. Suggest looking there. (been a while since I've looked a django migrations. Apologies if this is vague or wrong).

Comment: MySQLWB would log any error responses on ```%AppData%\MySQL\Workbench\log``` for windows. It would be a good way to find out what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Adding new few fields to an existing model (table) is one reason for this problem. A way to go about this is simply as follows:
a) un-apply the migrations for that app:

```
python3 manage.py migrate --fake <app-name> zero
```

b) migrate the required migrations (you've already deleted previous migrations and you've done 'makemigrations' for the newly added column. So, you just migrate:

```
python3 manage.py migrate <app-name>
```

If the steps above didn't solve the problems, then drop the table first:

**Be careful, if you have any data in the DB, they will be lost as well!!**

```
i) python3 manage.py dbshell

ii) DROP TABLE appname_tablename
```

close the shell and repeat a and b again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the app with the migrations is in the INSTALLED_APPS. Django won't look at the app for changes otherwise.